# Spyder crashes in Anaconda 4.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I am installing Python 2 via Anaconda 4.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to use spyder as my IDE.

When I first load spyder, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/bin/spyder", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numexpr/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
```

This error is solved by either copying the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 library to ~/anaconda2/lib, or by running conda update libgcc.

After this is completed, when I run spyder, I get a Segmentation Fault. Does anyone have any ideas what the issue might be here?

Comment: Is this other post useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294499/spyder-anaconda-crashes-on-linux-with-segmentation-fault