# Spyder anaconda crashes on Linux with segmentation fault

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I just installed Anaconda on Linux. When trying to open spyder (either from navigator or terminal), it does not work. I get the following error when I try to open it in terminal:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I updated Conda completely but can't solve the problem. I am using Conda version 4.5.5 and Ubuntu 18.04. Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you open a system terminal (xterm, konsole), run there `conda install pyopengl` and try again?

Comment: It worked Carlos, Thanks!

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer below then.

Comment: Switching to TkAgg backend for matplotlib solved something similar for me. It wasn't sypder, it was ipython but is suspect the same underlying problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is caused by faulty graphical card drivers and there are two ways to fix it:

1. Update to Spyder 3.3 or higher.
2. Install `pyopengl` with conda.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me on Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64 installed on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. First I updated spyder with `conda update spyder`. Then installed PyOpenGL with `conda install pyopengl`. Then opened `anaconda-navigator`, and manually updated all the applications by clicking on the gear icon.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my experiences, if you have ubuntu 18.04, anaconda 4.5 or higher, and spyder 3.3 or higher, installing `pyopengl` **does not** work, since spyder 3.3 should handle it. As recommended above, before start fixing it try to update spyder first:

```
conda update spyder
```

then **downgrade Qt**:

```
conda install pyqt=5.6
```

It should probably fix your problem. Other solutions could be found here:

[Spyder Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ)

as well as :

[Basic Troubleshooting](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ#basic-first-aid-general-troubleshooting) and [Emergency CPR](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ#emergency-cpr-spyder-wont-launch)

Answer (score 0):

I saw issue on brand new Fedora with new anaconda installation. Just updating the spyder to latest version (in my case 3.3.1) fixed it, without anything else.

(BTW: You can do this even from anaconda navigator itself, just look after the wheel within each application panel in the right corner).

Would recommend to fix anything stepwise, start with upgrading to the latest spyder and if this doesn't work, try the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions around here did not work for me. I have uninstalled Anaconda https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ and reinstalled it https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

Only then did the segmentation fault disappear.

Note that this has worked with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (a old release at the time of this writing) and Anaconda3 5.3.0 with Spyder 3.3.1 (the very latest); versions checked with `conda list <package>`. The Spyder version supported by Ubuntu 14 is still 2.5.5, so this arrangement lets me have on board a new Spyder without upgrading the distro. Not to mention that reportedly the developers prefer to maintain Spyder in the Anaconda environment rather than elsewhere.