# Spyder3 installation problem: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, spyder

I have Spyder2 working fine on my Ubuntu. I wanted Spyder3, however after installing it I am not able to run it using command spyder3:

```
spyder3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the only way I can run it is using:

```
python3 .local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py
```

I am not using Anaconda. Any idea how to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: I have this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51995619/10819438 .

I have Anaconda 1.9.6, Spyder 3.3.3 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Simone. However the solution you provided if for Ubuntu 18.04 while mine is Ubuntu 16.04.5. I also don't have anaconda.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can try with this other solution, I used it in the past for an old Ubuntu distribution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51306671/10819438.
Anaconda is a for package management, so if you don't have it maybe you can try to use `pip` to install or downgrade the package as explained in the link I sent you.